# What is an (int) prefix on floating point arithmetic actually doing?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In some sample code I see this syntax being used:

```
float1 = 7.0
float2 = 2.0
result = (int)(float1/float2)
```

The point seems to be to force the result to an integer, but I can't find any place that documents the `(int)` syntax being used, or why it would be preferable to `int(float1/float2)`.  A call to int() itself is supposed to return zero, but `(0)(float1/float2)` throws a TypeError and complains about zero not being a callable.  It's obvious the interpreter is trying to execute the int() reference, but it's not clear to me why it would expect to find a callable there.

Can someone point me to some documentation on this syntax?

Comment: I think you wanted to write `float1/float2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whoever wrote that code had too much exposure to languages that are more closely related to C than Python is. In C, C++, Java, C# and others, `(int)something` is the syntax to cast `something` to `(int)`. In Python, it's just a strange way to spell `int(something)`. `int` is the builtin function which converts `something` to an `int`.

In general, the Python expression `(<expr>)` for some other expression `<expr>` just evaluates to the same thing as `<expr>`. The parantheses can only affect precedence, but in this case they don't. Likewise, `<expr>(...)` evaluates `<expr>` and then calls the result -- note that `<expr>` can again be any expression, it's not limited to simple function names.

`(x)(y)` is the same as `x(y)`. `(int)(y)` works because `int(y)` works. `(0)(y)` doesn't because `0(y)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In this code: `result = (int)(float/float2)`

`(int)` is an expression that is evaluated to return the `int` function. That then is called with a single argument, the expression `float/float2`.

It doesn't work for `(0)` because the result of that expression is a number, which is not a callable type, exactly as the `TypeError` states.

Answer (score 3):

`(int)` evaluates to `int`, so

```
result = (int)(float/float2)
```

is the same as

```
result = int(float/float2)
```

Placing unnecessary parentheses around bare variable names is not recommended.